# Database with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My data json :

[image]

My code :

```
import json
import re
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('chinook.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
c = conn.cursor()

with open('tem.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:
     data = json.load(json_file)
     for p in data:
         data[p] = re.sub("<[^>]+>", "", str(data[p]))
         print("%s: %s" % (p, data[p]))
         c.execute("insert INTO THINH (THONGTIN, ID) VALUES ('"+ data[p] +"','"+ p +"')")
 conn.commit()
```

I cant get all data in json file into my database ?

[image]

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.  The command prompt text is not readable; paste it as text.

Comment: You are not using `sqlite3` correctly. Look at [sqlite doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) and search for `executemany`. 

Update your code to prepare `list` of `tuples` of your data (e.g [(THONGTIN1, ID1), (T2, ID2), ..]) and then do something line `c.executemany("INSERT INTO THINH VALUES (?,?)", list_of_datatuples)`.